# mysql query for cumulative sum

Tags: mysql

Actual table:

```
 ID Oc_date    marks
  1 25-Jul-15   10
  2 26-Jul-15   10
  3 27-Jul-15   10
  4 28-Jul-15   10
  5 29-Jul-15   10
```

Required result:

```
  1 25-Jul-15   10
  2 26-Jul-15   20
  3 27-Jul-15   30
  4 28-Jul-15   40
  5 29-Jul-15   50
```

Need a simple query to get this output.

Answer (score 0):

I think below SQL useful to you.

```
set @csum := 0;
select ID,  Oc_date, marks, (@csum := @csum + marks) as cumulative_sum
from YourTable
order by id;
```

Thank you.